# download audio from youtube like website

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I have a really simple question that I couldn't find any answer for.
the thing is that I need to be able to download audio from YouTube like website without any kind of plug-ins or standalone software, I came across something called webrtc, I know it only works with mozilla and chrome web browsers but that's fine with me any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm not not familiar with Webrtc, but you said it's fine with you. So why not giving it a try and post here your efforts :)

Comment: do you want to download only audio or both audio & video

Comment: technicalities aside, is that legal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get you right, you need some kind of a webapp to download only the audio form a video sharing websites like YouTube.

Try **[KeepVid](http://keepvid.com/)**